# Python 3.4 homework, I only want a hint

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a program that takes a prefix and list of words to return a list containing `True` or `False` for each word in the list, depending on whether the word starts with the prefix or not.
eg `starts_with('bob', ['bobastic', 'bobo', 'fandango']`
should return `[True, True, False]`.

This is what I have.

```
def starts_with(prefix, wordlist):
    lop= len(prefix)
    if lop==0:
        return True
    elif prefix[0] != [[x[0]] for x in wordlist]:
        return False
    else:
        wordrest = [x[1:] for x in wordlist]
        prefix_list = [starts_with(prefix[1:], wordrest)]
        return prefix_list
print(starts_with('bob', ['bobo', 'bobastic']))
```

and this function is acting funny, it checks that 'bob' and 'bobastic' start with "b" like 'bob' but instead of goin to the recursive case returns False.

I don't want a solution, if someone can point out to me what's going on, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you want a hint, here it is -- go study all the methods available to string objects, and see if one of them doesn't get you at least halfway there.

Comment: Does it have to be implemented in this recursive way? Seems like a regex would be a lot simpler.

Comment: You `return` in the `else` case - and there's no recursive call

Comment: @Patrick Maupin I don't think this is a good advice. Since this is a homework and a basic one on top of that I do believe the purpose of this task is **not** to use predefined string functions but implement things your own way with as few out of the box tools as possible.

Comment: @alfasin correct me if I'm wrong but isn't `prefix_list = [starts_with(prefix[1:], wordrest)]` a recursive call? ;)

Comment: @rbaleksandar -- Unless you have seen the actual assignment, you are merely speculating, as I am.  _My_ speculation is that it is probably perfectly fine to use the built-in string function and that the teacher wants to see a loop or recursion built on top of it.

Comment: Yeah, might be. The OP should clarify that omho.

Comment: @rbaleksandar oh missed it. Interesting though, this function is supposed to return either: `True` or `False`. Which means that this "recursive call" will evaluate `prefix_list` to be either `[True]` or `[False]`...

Comment: @rbaleksandar The instructor did not prohibit anything in particular but he hasn't taught too many predefined string functions. I doubt he'd mark them wrong, but I dont wanna risk it.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in here

```
elif prefix[0] != [[x[0]] for x in wordlist]:
    return False
```

in your example that would evaluate to:

```
'b' != [['b'],['b']]
```

witch will always be true

Answer (score 1):

just got a mail saying that the question was wrongly put, the professor just wanted us to return a list with those words that have the prefix.

the solution to the corrected version of the question (I think) is
 
`def starts_with(prefix, wordlist)`
          `return [x for x in wordlist if x[:len(prefix)]==prefix]`
Thank you all so much for your help. I hope I wasn't disrespectful to anyone (first question on SO ever!). If I was, I humbly apologize. Have nice day!

Answer (score 0):

As @DorElias mentioned, the `elif` condition is wrong because it tries to compare a character to a list - it will always fail!

You can fix it by using the built-in function [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
def starts_with(prefix, wordlist):
    if not len(prefix):
        return True
    elif all([prefix[0] == x[0] for x in wordlist]):
        wordrest = [x[1:] for x in wordlist]
        return starts_with(prefix[1:], wordrest)
    else:
        return False

print(starts_with('bob', ['bobo', 'bobastic']))
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to write a function (recursive or not) that will check if a single word starts_with a given prefix - test it and get it working.

```
def prefix(pre, word):
    '''Return True if pre is a prefix of word.
    '''
    # your code here
```

Then you can write a second function that takes the prefix and a sequence of words as arguments and iterates over the words calling the other function on each word

```
def starts_with(pre, word_list):
    '''Determine if each word in word_list starts with pre.

    returns a list of True,False
    '''
    # construct a list
    # add prefix(pre, word) to list
    # for each word in word_list
```

Comment: I think I have the first function
`def begins_with(word, prefix):`
    `lop= len(prefix)`
    `if len(word)<lop:`
        `return "False"`
    `elif lop==0:`
        `return "True"`
    `elif word[0]!=prefix[0]:`
        `return "False"`
    `else:`
        `prefix_rest = begins_with(word[1:],prefix[1:])`
        `return prefix_rest`

Comment: @user5381923, if you are going to change your strategy and use two functions, you should start a new question if you are having trouble with the new approach.  Also, you are allowed to answer your own question if you come up with a suitable solution.